# How to integrate Google Sheet API using client side JavaScript using Firebase Auth?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-sheets, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I am using React for frontend development and have integrated Firebase Google Authentication into my app. Now I have requirement for integrating Google Sheet into my app through which my users can maintain their spreadsheets.

I came to know that to access Google APIs I need Oauth2 token so I went to [Firebase Auth documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk) and found that we can add scopes into the google auth provider which in results give the Oauth2 credentials. So I added Google spreadsheet scopes and now when I try to login, it is asking me the permissions and I am also getting that Oauth credentials.

Now the problem I am facing is to use that token to access the spreadsheet APIs. I tried `gapi` into my project and passing that token into it but it throws error which says that

> API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal.

This is my code

```
    const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
        try {
            console.log('Google sign-in started');
            const result = await signInWithPopup(
                auth,
                googleProvider.addScope(
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
                )
            );
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
            const token = credential.accessToken;
            console.log(credential, token);

            //creating a spreadsheet
            try {
                gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.create({
                    auth:token,
                    properties: {
                        title: "My spreadsheet",
                    },
                }).then((response) => {
                    // if (callback) callback(response);
                    console.log('Spreadsheet ID: ' + response.result.spreadsheetId);
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }

        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            throw err;
        }
    };
```

In `index.html` file I have added these scripts

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

In `App.js` file I have initialized gapi in the `useEffect`

```
    useEffect(() => {
        /* global gapi */
        gapi.load('client', async () => {
            await gapi.client.init({
                apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
                discoveryDocs: [
                    'https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4',
                ],
                // clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
                // scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
            });
        });

        function gisLoaded() {
            tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
                client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
                callback: '', // defined later
            });
           
            console.log('Token', tokenClient);
        }
        gisLoaded();
    }, []);
```

What I am missing here?